# Using an op amp as conditional

Tags: led, operational-amplifier

My professor gave out this instructions: Use an op amp with to leds connected to the output, one LED needs to turn on (while the other is off) when you have 2v as an input and when you change the input to 1 the other LED needs to turn on.

Those are all the instructions we were given he said we could not use logic gates or anything like that. To be honest I have no idea of how to do it, I'm not asking you to do my homework but if you could point me in the right direction it would be really helpful.

Comment: You know an opamp is basically a voltage comparator?

Comment: *cough* back to back LED's *cough*

Answer (score 3):

You can use an opamp as a voltage comparator. Without feedback, the output will basically stick to the positive or negative power rail according to the sign of the voltage between IN+ and IN-. All the opamp does is amplify the voltage between its inputs by "a huge amount of gain".

It won't be a good comparator: in this role, opamps are slower, the output might not get close to the power rails (depending on the opamp) but it'll work. If all you need is to light a LED, then no problem.

Note this homework will teach you bad habits. You shouldn't use opamps as comparators unless you have a dual opamp somewhere in the design, and one opamp is unused, and you can tolerate the bad performance. If you want a fast comparator (like <1µs) then use a comparator.

Answer (score 3):

First it's bad practice to use op-amps as comparators. Some op-amps have back-to-back diodes across the inputs. Op-amps are designed to have approximately zero differential voltage in normal operation. Internally compensated op-amps (most that are available) are also very slow.

Anyway, if you have a voltage Vref on the inverting input and apply a voltage Vin > Vref to the non-inverting input the output will approach the positive rail. If Vin < Vref the output will approach the negative rail. It would seem you would want to compare Vin to a voltage somewhere between 1 and 2V (decide what makes sense here).

If you have a dual supply the output voltage (say with a +/-15V supply) will go from (say) +13V to -13V. Now you can figure out what to do with that to make one LED light vs. the other. Keep in mind that the reverse voltage on the LED should not exceed a few volts (5V is usually okay). There is a very simple way to do it and some less simple ways.

Comment: +1 for "There is a very simple way to do it and some less simple ways." now you have everyone guessing what the simple one is ;)